# add image wirh entity media browser in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I add module entity media browser and i add media filed in content type also Ienable module entity media browser .. now when I have add new content I have this error and I blocked in this page

[image]

how to resolve this error please
 .. I'm blocked my friends

Comment: Any help please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Any help please